# Переопределение стилей в Android

Tags: android, android-style, android-themes

Не могу разобраться как переопределить стили в android. Main Activity наследуется от AppCompatActivity. Дефолтные кнопки серого цвета.
Назначаю оттенки так.

```
lowBtn.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_state_list));
```

button_state_list.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/color_btn_candidate" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#000" />

</selector>
```

После нажатия мне нужно вернуть кнопке дефолтный стиль. Но я не могу найти его. Кликая по сслыкам parent на теме приложения AppTheme ухожу в неведомые дебри. Как найти и переопределить искомый стиль и что именно нужно переопределять ведь у каждой версии api > 21 как я понял своя тема?

Comment: Цвет кнопки определяется атрибутом `android:colorButtonNormal`

Comment: Ну... В книге “Android. Программирование для профессионалов” сказано, что искать нужный тебе атрибут зачастую приходится именно так, кликая на родителя и вглядываясь в название атрибутов.

Comment: Попробовал сослаться на ?attr/colorButtonNormal. Цвет стал красный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вернуть серый цвет при клике, надо вызвать:

```
lowBtn.setBackgroundTintList(null);
```